# Firefox does not read local time on Windows

Tags: javascript, datetime, firefox

I discovered what appears to be a bug in Firefox on Windows while using the MomentJS library. However, this appears to be a bug in Firefox `Date()` itself.

The problem is with obtaining the local time with the [getTimezoneOffset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) function as well as other local time functions like the [getHours()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours) function. It does not get the local time offset at all on Windows. The other browsers, including the same version of Firefox on OSX, get the correct time.

Here is my setup:

OSX: 10.10.5

- Chrome: 48.0.2564.82
- Firefox: 43.0.4

Windows: 7, SP1, current on updates

- Chrome: 48.0.2564.82
- Internet Explorer 11.0.9.9600.18163
- Firefox: 43.0.4

#### OSX:

- Chrome:

  ```
  new Date() 
  # Thu Jan 21 2016 10:07:23 GMT-0700 (MST)

  new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
  # 420 (minutes, correct)

  new Date().getHours()
  # 10 (this is correct, since I am -07:00 UTC)
  ```
- Firefox:

  ```
  new Date() 
  # Date 2016-01-21T17:03:49.807Z

  new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
  # 420 (minutes, correct)

  new Date().getHours()
  # 10 (correct)
  ```

#### Windows:

- Chrome:

  ```
  new Date() 
  # Thu Jan 21 2016 10:10:41 GMT-0700 (MST)

  new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
  # 420 (minutes, correct)

  new Date().getHours()
  # 10 (correct)
  ```
- Internet Explorer:

  ```
  new Date() 
  # Thu Jan 21 2016 10:16:09 GMT-0700 (MST)

  new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
  # 420 (minutes, correct)

  new Date().getHours()
  # 10 (correct)
  ```
- Firefox:

  ```
  new Date() 
  # Date 2016-01-21T17:12:43.807Z

  new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
  # 0 (INCORRECT)

  new Date().getHours()
  # 17 (INCORRECT - No timezone offset)
  ```

As far as I can tell, this is just a bug in Firefox on Windows. Is that correct? Do I have any misunderstandings about how that function (and other local timezone functions) are supposed to work?

Comment: Can't reproduce in Win10. Works fine.

Comment: Same here, for Win 7 (SP1/current updates as well) and Firefox 43.0.4 (so pretty much the same setup as yours?) – I get `Date {Thu Jan 21 2016 18:43:30 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)}`, `-60` and `18`

Comment: Thanks for the quick checks @j08691 and @CBroe. It turns out the issue was the presence of a `TZ` environment variable on my machine (see my response below). I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the Firefox will look for a `TZ` environment variable on Windows and try to use that to set the local time zone. I found this [old Mozilla bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=173431) that helped me figure this out.

We were using the `TZ` environment variable for our server side application. I renamed the variable, and now everything is working as expected.

Comment: I ran into this same issue, thanks for this suggestion. You saved me hours!